# javascript check if url contains a numeric value

Tags: javascript

As above. How do i check if a URL contains a numeric value and get that value if it is there

```
for example 
http://myurl.com/home/1234567
```

I want to check if the url contains a 7 digit number as the last item and if so display it. 
Is there any quick way to do this?

Comment: `url.match(/\d{7}$/)`

Comment: @dandavis you forgot about slash before the number

Comment: @pwolaq: no i didn't, OP wants digits only. feel free to offer a more robust version.

Comment: Also, use `location.pathname` instead of `href`. This way you can skip query params

Comment: @dandavis thanks.... can you explain the regex to me?

Comment: Would also be good to account for a URL that has ending slashes.  Maybe `location.pathname.match(/\/\d{7}(?:\/*)$/)`

Comment: @blu10 `\d` looks for a digit, `{7}` matches the previous symbol 7 times, and `$` at the end means "end of string". It's looking for 7 digits and then the end of the URL string.